# How to benchmark the Resque perform method or the Resque Job class?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, benchmarking, resque

I'm using Resque, Resque-Status and Resque-Retry to process the bkg jobs.
Following is an example job. It performs queries against 4-5 models.
Now I want to give a try to use [Sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq) which boasts on its speed over Resque.

But before that, I want to benchmark my following job in my rails app to verify later that which performs best.

```
class BkgJob < Resque::JobWithStatus
  extend Resque::Plugins::Retry
  @retry_limit = 3
  @retry_delay = 60

  @queue = :critical

  def perform
    worker_id, station_id, ids = options['worker_id'], options['station_id'], options['ids']
    human_worker = Worker.find(human_worker_id)
    station = Station.find(station_id)
    .....
    .....
  end
end
```

So, the question is how to benchmark the above job-class or perform method? I'm really newbie in the benchmarking.

Answer (score 0):

Performance of the job you are running in background will be almost the same for Resque or Sidekiq. However, Sidekiq is MUCH faster at picking jobs from the queue, and is much more memory efficient compared to Resque.

Benchmarking of your background jobs is still a good idea, but I'd say you should only benchmark the perform method itself and not the whole process of queueing and executing the job. You can do something like this (an RSpec example):

```
require 'benchmark'

describe 'performance' do
  it 'takes time' do
    options = {'worker_id': 123, 'station_id': 456, 'ids': [1,2,3]}
    puts Benchmark.realtime do
       100.times { BkgJob.new(options).perform }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanx for the reply. But I'm still concerned about the DB calls that will happen inside the job. e.g. Though you passed the options hash, when the perform is called, those db calls will still be called `Station.find(station_id)` ? Am I clear enough or missing some scenarios?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear enough. You wouldn't need these DB calls inside the job once you switched to Sidekiq. Basically, when the job gets queued, Sidekiq serializes arguments with `YAML.dump()` and when the job started, it deserializes arguments with 'YAML.load()'. In Ruby you can dump to YAML any object with all its attributes, including ActiveRecord objects. And when the object is loaded from the dump, it is kind of ready to be used without further queries to DB.

Comment: In your application you can try running `station_dump = YAML.dump(Station.first)`, then `station = YAML.load(station)` will give you the same Station object you dumped to the string. Of course, there are some caveats, for example, if the station was deleted between the calls, your restored station object will have all the attributes, but it will give an error if you try to save it. But having this in mind, serialization of job arguments to YAML saves you database hits and gives some performance gain.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. Its helpful on how the sidekiq differs from Resque knowing the internals. Based upon your explanation, I am understanding that while doing benchmarking, one should use a pre-built data instead of hitting the actual db calls. Am I right? or do I need to really hit the db?

Comment: No, I don't mean you should use a pre-built data. When you benchmark Resque, you should just benchmark the current method that hits the DB. Then you rewrite the job for Sidekiq, and because it allows you to pass objects as arguments of the job, you can remove the `find` statments from the job. Your `perform` method will look like `def perform(worker, station, whatever)`, and there will be no need to hit the DB. But again, this is just a small hint for Sidekiq jobs, and not the main selling point of Sidekiq.

Comment: Passing whole objects instead of ids is a bad idea, according to Sidekiq's documentation: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Best-Practices. It's also been my experience that serializing / deserializing objects to and from YAML is troublesome at best. Besides the object getting deleted, what if it were edited before your delayed job edited and saved the object. Prior changes get lost, or the save fails because you've now violated some validation rule. Or your business logic goes down the wrong path because it's looking at old data. It's not worth the performance gain.

Comment: @sockmonk I cannot disagree with your comment. I remove the advise to pass objects as job arguments from my answer. Though it can give some performance boost to background jobs, that was a bad idea.